# dynamic matrix initialization error

Tags: c

I got an error `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` while trying to initialize a dynamic matrix using this function:

```
int** allocate_matrix_solid(int n, int m)
{
    int **data = malloc(n * sizeof(int*) +n * m * sizeof(int));
    if (!data)
    return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        data[i] = (int*)((char*) data + n * sizeof(int*) + i * m * sizeof(int));
    return data;
}


int** data = allocate_matrix_solid(2,2);
```

Where could there be the mistake?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? And please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: You have `#include <stdlib.h>` in your source file, *right* ?

Comment: It looks like a compiler error; please also list the compiler version and any command line arguments.

Comment: It compiles with c11 mode. https://wandbox.org/permlink/JewmHWl2jICUC2QZ

Comment: Why are you allocating more than `int **data = malloc(n * sizeof *data);` pointers? and why are you allocating more than `data[i] = malloc (m * sizeof *data[i]);` integers to simulate an `nxm` matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't allocate and simulate a 2D array (a.k.a matrix) that way and have it do anything but be 100% non-portable between 32-bit and 64-bit machines. Why?

With `int **data = malloc(n * sizeof(int*) +n * m * sizeof(int));` you allocate `n-pointers + n * m integers` which effectively allocates `n + n * m` pointers on a 32-bit box and `n + (n * m)/2` pointers on a 64-bit box. While you are getting creative attempting to index `data[i] = (int*)((char*) data + n * sizeof(int*) + i * m * sizeof(int));`, it is a recipe for disaster and likely breaks pointer-arithmetic.

Simulating a 2D array where `n` and `m` are unknown at compile time is a 2-step process. First you allocate/validate storage for `n-pointers` and then allocate/validate storage for `m-integers` assigning the beginning address in each new block to your `data[i]`. If `m` is a constant, then you can allocate using a *pointer-to-array-of-type []* and allocate at once with `n * m * sizeof (type)`, but you do not have `int (*data)[2]` you have `int **data` which are two fundamentally different types requiring two different approaches to allocation.

If you want to simulate the 2D array (matrix) and allocate storage for pointers and data, you will do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NROW 2
#define NCOL 2

int **allocate_matrix_solid (int n, int m)
{
    int **data = malloc (n * sizeof *data);    /* allocate n pointers */
    if (!data)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = calloc (m, sizeof *data[i]); /* allocate m integers */
        if (!data[i])         /* calloc used to initilize memory zero */
            return NULL;
    }
    return data;
}

int main (void) {

    int **data = allocate_matrix_solid (NROW, NCOL);
    if (!data) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: allocate_matrix_solid failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NROW; i++) {    /* output matrix */
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)
            printf (" %2d", data[i][j]);
        free (data[i]);                 /* free integers */
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    free (data);                        /* free pointers */
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/allocmatrix
  0  0
  0  0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Typically a "roll-your-own" indexing scheme mixing pointers and data in one big block of memory is just a bad idea.